# Ajax alert on success response not working c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of code that inserts some contact details using ajax and c#
The code runs through and the db is updated with the record but the alert box for a success doesnt seem to show.  It does seem to work if I debug through the javascript debugger in chrome, it will hit that piece of code and the alert will show.  But not otherwise.

Here is the code:

Javascript

```
function insertDonator() {

    var title = $("#DropDownTitle option:selected").text();
    var FirstName = $("#txtFirstNameinput").val();
    var LastName = $("#txtLastNameInput").val();
    var Add1 = $("#txtAdd1").val();
    var Add2 = $("#txtAdd2").val();
    var Town = $("#txtTown").val();
    var County = $("#txtCounty").val();
    var PostCode = $("#txtPostCode").val();
    var telephone = $("#txtPhoneInput").val();
    var email = $("#txtEmailInput").val();
    var collectionArea = $("#txtCollectionAreaInput").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService1.asmx/insertDonator",

        data: '{title:"' + title + '", FirstName: "' + FirstName + '",LastName:"' + LastName + '", Add1:"' + Add1 + '", Add2: "' + Add2 + '",Town:"' + Town + '",County:"' + County + '",PostCode:"' + PostCode + '",telephone:"' + telephone + '",email:"' + email + '",collectionArea:"' + collectionArea + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: OnSuccess,

        failure: function (response) {

            Apprise(response.d);
        }
    }
    )

}



function OnSuccess(response) {
   alert("Record added");

}
```

HTML (aspx file)

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnaddRecord" runat="server" Text="Add Donator" OnClientClick="insertDonator();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not cancelling the default action of the button click. Normally you can use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), but you can also retrun false in the click event.

```
OnClientClick="insertDonator(); return false;"
```

Comment: thanks works great even though I dont exactly understand why thats needed!

Comment: What does a submit button do? It submits the form back to the server. You are intercepting the click and handling the form submission, so you need to cancel the click so the default action of submitting the form does not take place.